# Conditional Mass Function $f(y|x) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f(x)} = \frac{\color{red}{f(x|y)f(y)}}{f(x)}$

Tags: probability

How do I get $f(x, y) = f(x|y)f(y)$ in the below equation?

$$f(y|x) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f(x)} = \frac{\color{red}{f(x|y)f(y)}}{f(x)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:
$$
f(x,y) = \dfrac{f(y)}{f(y)} \cdot f(x,y) = \dfrac{f(x,y)}{f(y)} \cdot f(y) = f(x|y)f(y)
$$
If you're confused as to what I did, it may help to read these equations from right to left.